# how to download images to a folder in php

Tags: php, image, curl

I want to download a image from the url but it is not getting downloaded.Please check out the code and tell me where i am going wrong.

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init ("http://l1.yimg.com/t/frontpage/cannes_anjelina_60.jpg");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1);
$rawdata=curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
$fp = fopen("img.jpg",'w');
fwrite($fp, $rawdata);
fclose($fp);
?>
```

Comment: Get any errors?  Can you set `error_reporting(E_ALL)`?

Answer (score 1):

It's working fine, set proper file permissions to where the image should be saved. In this case it's the same folder where your script is, might want to move it somewhere else like:

```
// where "images" folder can be written with files
// set permissions to 0755
$fp = fopen("images/img.jpg",'w');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function download_image ($url, $the_filename) {

    $cookie = tempnam ("/tmp", "CURLCOOKIE");
    $ch = curl_init ($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Debian) Firefox/0.10.1");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 5);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://tomakefast.com");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, false);
    $rawdata=curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    file_put_contents("../somewhere/". $the_filename, $rawdata);

}
```

If you see any problems, please let me know.  This occasionally gives me a 0 byte image file but that could happen for any number of reasons.  This could be improved to return false on 0 bytes, maybe even do a basic test to see if indeed an image was downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this simple code instead if you feel this is better.

```
$img_file = file_get_contents("http://l1.yimg.com/t/frontpage/cannes_anjelina_60.jpg");
file_put_contents("myImage.jpg", $img_file);
```