# cURL-ed image remains 0 bytes

Tags: php, curl

I am using cURL to retrieve an image, rename it and store it locally.
The images comes up as 0 byte file, no matter, whether I use cURL, like so:

```
$strImageUrl = curl_init($strImageUrlSource);
$fp = fopen($strTargetImage, 'wb');
curl_setopt($strImageUrl, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($strImageUrl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_exec($strImageUrl);
curl_close($strImageUrl);
fclose($fp);
```

or file_put/get. like so:

```
file_put_contents($strImageName, file_get_contents($strImageUrlSource));
```

The URL I am retrieving is:

> <img src='http://i1.au.reastatic.net/150x112/73fa6c02a92d60a76320d0e89dfbc1a36a6e46c818f74772dec65bae6959c62f/main.jpg' width="150" height="112" alt="Wondecla, address available on request" title="Wondecla, address available on request" />

I can save this image properly manually.
When looking at the properties in FireFox it shows three entries:

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAFgAAABYBAMAAACDuy0HAAAAG1BMVEX+/v4BAQH///8KCgoDAwN/f3/19fWAgID8... etc
```

http://i1.au.reastatic.net/150x112/73fa6c02a92d60a76320d0e89dfbc1a36a6e46c818f74772dec65bae6959c62f/main.jpg

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KG ... etc.
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: It's possible there was a timeout, redirect, hotlink protection or something of that nature.  You might want to play with other curl options allowing redirects, etc.  See my solution here http://stackoverflow.com/a/18927806/722796

Comment: BTW this deletes all the size zero images in Linux: 
find /home/somewhere/images -type f -size 0 -exec rm {} \;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

**Using file_get_contents**

```
$image = 'http://i1.au.reastatic.net/150x112/73fa6c02a92d60a76320d0e89dfbc1a36a6e46c818f74772dec65bae6959c62f/main.jpg';

$imageName = pathinfo( $image, PATHINFO_BASENAME );

file_put_contents( $imageName, file_get_contents( $image ) );
```

**Using CURL**

```
$image = 'http://i1.au.reastatic.net/150x112/73fa6c02a92d60a76320d0e89dfbc1a36a6e46c818f74772dec65bae6959c62f/main.jpg';

$imageName = pathinfo( $image, PATHINFO_BASENAME );

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $image );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );

$source = curl_exec( $ch );
curl_close( $ch );

file_put_contents( $imageName, $source );
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use var_dump() to debug. What do you see when you

```
var_dump(file_get_contents('http://i1.au.reastatic.net/150x112/73fa6c02a92d60a76320d0e89dfbc1a36a6e46c818f74772dec65bae6959c62f/main.jpg'));
```